# Make triangle animation stretch instead of move

Tags: html, css, animation

I would like the  moving overlay triangle in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbnwj3ag/) to stretch its animation to fit the forest image. The problem as you see now is that it creates whitespace at the top and its moving the triangle instead of stretching it. If anyone got a smart solution please comment.

i tried modifying these values but can't get it working properly.

```
border-left: 47.5vw solid transparent;
border-right: 47.5vw solid transparent;
border-top: 95vh solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fbnwj3ag/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work, because you have 95vw (2x 47.5) width of border(left/right), 95vh of border top and you just move it down with translate. I think that better way is to manipulate border-width in animation

```
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        border-left-width: 47.5vw; 
        border-right-width: 47.5vw; 
        left: 2.5vw;
        border-top-width:95vh;
        top: -5vh;
    }

    40% {
        border-left-width: 50vw;
        border-right-width: 50vw;
        left: 0;
        border-top-width: 100vh; 
        top: 0vh;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2j29b9d4/

Answer (score 1):

Just change the "bounce" animation. Add scale property.

```
.bounce {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    }

    40% {
        -webkit-transform: translateY(10vh) scale(2);
    }
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {
        transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateY(10vh) scale(2);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fbnwj3ag/5/